# compare function for upper_bound / lower_bound

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to find the first item in a sorted vector that has a field less than some value x.
I need to supply a compare function that compares 'x' with the internal value in MyClass but I can't work out the function declaration.
Can't I simply overload '<' but how do I do this when the args are '&MyClass' and 'float' ?

```
 float x;
 std::vector< MyClass >::iterator last = std::upper_bound(myClass.begin(),myClass.end(),x);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What function did you pass to the sort algorithm? You should be able to use the same one for upper_bound and lower_bound.

The easiest way to make the comparison work is to create a dummy object with the key field set to your search value. Then the comparison will always be between like objects.

**Edit:** If for some reason you can't obtain a dummy object with the proper comparison value, then you can create a comparison functor. The functor can provide three overloads for operator() :

```
struct MyClassLessThan
{
    bool operator() (const MyClass & left, const MyClass & right)
    {
        return left.key < right.key;
    }
    bool operator() (const MyClass & left, float right)
    {
        return left.key < right;
    }
    bool operator() (float left, const MyClass & right)
    {
        return left < right.key;
    }
};
```

As you can see, that's the long way to go about it.

Comment: That was the problem, the sort function takes two const refs to MyClass objects. The search function must take a MyClass and a float. Same problem for using bind2nd() the

Comment: operator() to compare things - now why didn't I think of that !!!
The more I use STL the more I love python.     
thank you

Comment: @chmike, Yes, of course. Thanks. Wonder why it took so long for anyone to notice?

Answer (score 9):

You can further improve Mark's solution by creating a static instance of MyClassLessThan in MyClass

```
class CMyClass 
{
   static struct _CompareFloatField
   {
      bool operator() (const MyClass & left, float right) //...
      // ...
   } CompareFloatField;
};
```

This way you can call lower_bound in the following way:

```
std::lower_bound(coll.begin(), coll.end(), target, CMyClass::CompareFloatField);
```

This makes it a bit more readable

Comment: I would still need a dummy object and an operator() for each member - but your's is clearer in reading the intent - thanks

Answer (score 4):

Pass a lambda function to upper_bound

```
 float x;
 MyClass target;
 target.x_ = x;
 std::vector< MyClass >::iterator last = 
 std::upper_bound(myClass.begin(),myClass.end(),target, 
 [](const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b){return a.x_ < b.x_;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `std::bind2nd(std::less<MyClass>(), x)`.  But, of course, the operator< must be defined for MyClass.

Edit: oh and I think you will need a constructor for MyClass that accepts only a float so that it can be implicitly converted.  However, there might be a better way to do this.