# How to use lower_bound to insert value into sorted vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of pointer to class A which I want to keep sorted by int key using STL.  To do this I defined an `operator <` in class A

```
bool operator< (const A &lhs, const A &rhs){
    return (lhs.key < rhs.key);
};
```

and in my insert function it looks like

```
vector<A*>::iterator it = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), element);
vec.insert(it, element);
```

I expect `lower_bound` to return first place where the new element can be placed, but it does not work. Inserting A objects with keys 0,1,2,3 will result in vector in incorrect order (2,3,1,0). Why is that ?

Probably I could also use comparator for this object:

[compare function for upper_bound / lower_bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869593/compare-function-for-upper-bound-lower-bound)

but what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Using a vector of pointers is like shooting yourself in the foot and saying 'well at least I missed my head'. The whole point of vector is to save yourself from explicit heap memory management, but using a vector of pointers means you are still managing heap memory. Just use `vector<A>`, or `vector<shared_ptr<A>>`

Comment: @John. Why is that ? If this is bad practice I would probably try to change it

Comment: Why is what? Do you mean why is explicit heap memory management bad? Mainly because it's difficult and a rich source of bugs. There are 1000s and 1000s of posts on SO where the problem is that someone didn't do their `new` and `delete` properly. It's definitely considered bad practice.

Comment: @John. I posted my previos post without seeing your comment. I obviously agree with You. Ok, the reason I use Vector of pointers is that A is an abstract class, and there are many classes that have this vector<A*> and each keeps in it an object of class that inherits from A.

Comment: OK, that is a good reason, but you should still use a smart pointer such as `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Please use unique_ptr in preference of shared_ptr unless you know that you actually need shared_ptr. unique_ptr has simpler ownership semantics and is more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

From your example, you're using a vector of pointers: `std::vector<A*>`. Hence, you need to define a comparison for pointers which you pass in to `std::lower_bound`:

```
bool less_A_pointer (const A* lhs, const A* rhs)
{
    return (lhs->key < rhs->key);
}

auto it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), element, less_A_pointer);
//...
```

Of course, the question is why are you using pointers in the first place - just store `A` objects unless you really need to. If you do need to store pointers, look into  `std::shared_ptr` which will handle this for you:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v;
std::shared_ptr<A> element(new A(...));
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), element); //Will work properly
```

You can also use a lambda instead of having to write a free function:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                          [](const A* lhs, const A* rhs)
                          { return lhs->key < rhs->key; });
```

Comment: Don't use a vector of pointers would be the other possibility.

Comment: @Yuushi. Errors : operator <' must have at least one formal parameter of class type. and A:GetKey' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A &. int GetKey() returns private key.

Comment: I would consider using a lambda with `std::lower_bound`, and `auto` and `std::make_shared` for allocating the `shared_ptr`, e.g. `auto element = std::make_shared<A>(...);`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a `std::vector` of pointers, you may want to consider using a **smart pointer** like `std::shared_ptr`.
*Raw* pointers are OK if they are **observing** pointers, but generally you should *not* using *raw* **owning** pointers (unless in some special conditions).

You can pass a lambda to `std::lower_bound()`, to specify the sorting criteria (in this case, compare the key data members).

Moreover, instead of explicitly writing `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>::iterator` for the return value of `std::lower_bound()`, you could just use C++11's `auto` keyword, which makes the code more readable in this case.

A compilable code sample follows (compiled with g++ 4.8.0):

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::lower_bound
#include <iostream>     // for console output
#include <memory>       // for std::make_shared, std::shared_ptr
#include <string>       // for std::string
#include <vector>       // for std::vector
using namespace std;

// Test data structure
struct A
{
    int Key;
    string Data;

    A()
        : Key(0)
    {}

    A(int key, const string& data)
        : Key(key), Data(data)
    {}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
{
    os << "(key=" << a.Key << ", data=\"" << a.Data << "\")";
    return os;
}

void Print(const vector<shared_ptr<A>> & v)
{
    cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto & p : v)
    {
        cout << *p << " ";
    }
    cout << " ]\n";
}

int main()
{
    // Test container
    vector<shared_ptr<A>> v;

    // Test data
    const char* data[] = {
        "hello",
        "world",
        "hi",
        nullptr
    };

    // Index in data array
    int i = 0;

    // Insertion loop
    while (data[i] != nullptr)
    {
        // Create new element on the heap
        auto elem = make_shared<A>(i, data[i]);

        // Find ordered insertion position
        auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), elem,
            [](const shared_ptr<A>& lhs, const shared_ptr<A>& rhs)
            {
                return lhs->Key < rhs->Key;
            }
        );

        // Insert in vector
        v.insert(it, elem);

        // Move to next data
        i++;
    }

    // Show the result
    Print(v);
}
```

Here's the output:

> ```
> [ (key=2, data="hi") (key=1, data="world") (key=0, data="hello")  ]
> ```

Comment: "owining"? Typo.

Comment: your comparison lambda has a typo