# Lower_bound throws "error C2914: 'std::lower_bound' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

While trying to teach myself STL, I wrote the following class:

```
class Person{
public:
    ...
    bool operator<(const Person& p) const; // sorts by weight
    friend bool compareWeight(const Person &p, const int& wt); //true if wt<p.weight
    friend bool compareWeight(const int& wt, const Person &p);
    ...
private:
    int age;
    int weight;
};
```

Operator< is defined as:

```
bool Person::operator<(const Person& p) const{
    if (weight<p.weight)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
// get lower_bound for weight = 50
vector<Person>::iterator itr = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),50,compareWeight);
```

It throws:

```
error C2914: 'std::lower_bound':cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous
```

I can solve this using a dummy person, with weight = 50, and then calling lower_bound:

```
vector<Person>::iterator itr = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(), dummy);
```

But its obviously not very elegant, can someone please help me getting compareWeight to work? Also, any suggestions about best approach in such a case will be great. No Boost or C++11 please, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing the two friend functions, you can provide a single function object that will do both operations.

```
struct CompareWeight {
   bool operator()(const Person&, int) const;
   bool operator()(int, const Person&) const;
};
```

Then you can call the algorithm as:

```
std::lower_bound(std::begin(v), std::end(v), CompareWeight());
```

Note: I agree with jrok that only one overload should be needed, but it seems that your implementation (which need not fully comply with the standard) requires the other direction, if that is the case this provides for a simple workaround.

Comment: Item23, Page 104 in the book "Effective STL" says "(For associative containers) you can’t know whether the key value or the pair will be passed as the first argument, so you really need two comparison functions for lookups, one where the key value is passed first and one where the pair is passed first." Is this not applciable in the example I'm trying?

Comment: This Item popped in my mind when compiler raised an error about not being able to convert Person to int. And thats why I ended up overloading CompareWeight.

Comment: @InnocentRetard It doesn't apply, `vector` is a sequence container, not an associative container.

Comment: @jrok Of course, but please take a look at the accepted answer at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869593/compare-function-for-upper-bound-lower-bound

Comment: @InnocentRetard: The standard defines the operation, and the requirements there are stated in terms of comparisons of the form `cmp(*it,value)` where `it` is one of the iterators and `value` is the third argument to the `lower_bound` function. There is no requirement that `T` (type of that argument) is the same as `iterator::value_type`, nor is there any requirement that the comparison needs to be symmetric with respect to types.

Comment: Regarding the linked question, the answer is guaranteed to work (*sufficient*) but that is not the same as stating that providing the three comparisons is required (*necessary*).\

Answer (score 1):

Compiler needs to know the exact signature of the function to deduce the last argument of `lower_bound`. But since `compareWeight` is overloaded, it can't decide which one to take. Thus, you need to manualy cast to the right function pointer:

```
typedef bool(*Comp)(const Person&, const int&);
lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),50,static_cast<Comp>(&compareWeight));
```

Personaly, I'd do what you did with dummy parameter.

---

Off topic suggestion: pass primitive types by value, it's faster.

```
friend bool compareWeight(const Person &p, int wt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get the following error on trying your suggestions: "error C2664: 'bool (const Person &,const int &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Person' to 'const int &'" Infact getting rid of this error is why I overloaded compareWeight in the first place.

Comment: @InnocentRetard Is the vector storing `Person`s or `int`s? First parameter type of comparator must match with the type in the container, the second one with the type of third parameter to `lower_bound`.

Comment: If I remove `friend bool compWeight(const int& wt, const Person &p);` compiler complains `cannot convert parameter 2 from 'Person' to 'const int &'`

Comment: @InnocentRetard You haven't shown your exact code, so I can't be sure, but [it works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1849a25604b8a8328d4a2bae57e6b6e6-d453f8cdb05876c21842cb19504c959f)

Comment: @InnocentRetard: Are you using `compWeight` anywhere else?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas No, I'm not using it anywhere else.

Comment: @jrok In my code I create a bunch of persons and then push_back in the vector. I then sort the vector using the operator< and then call the lower_bound. I have added operator<'s definition in the question.

Comment: @InnocentRetard Maybe your standard lib's `lower_bound` passes the arguments in reversed order. Try casting to the other comparator type and see if it works. And note that if you want to use `operator<` with `lower_bound` you'll need a conversion from `int` to `Person`. Stuff I wrote in my answer applies only to `lower_bound` overload that takes a custom comparator.