# lower_bound functionality without creating T element

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a `T` class which has a property (`int f() const`). I have a vector of `T`s which is ordered in respect to this property. I want to perform a logarithmic search on the elements to find the first element where calling `f()` is not less than the input.

```
std::vector<T> v;
// Filling of v
int lob = 1234;
// This next line is an illustration of intent:
std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),lob
  ,/* ??? if(element.f() < lob) return true; */ );
```

A workaround is to create an instance of `T` which would return the value of `lob` when its `f()` is called. Let's say that creating a dummy `T` like this would be overly difficult. How can I perform this search without creating a `T`?

I can write the logarithmic search for this very problem, but I wonder if is there any generic solution for that. I'm interested in until and since C++11 solutions too.

Comment: Try creating a custom class Compare and using it's () operator as the last argument to std::lower_bound().

Comment: @AbhishekBansal And what would be a signature for that comparator? The problem begins when I give `lob` as 3rd parameter because its type is not `T`.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869593/compare-function-for-upper-bound-lower-bound

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I was wrong. I do can pass `lob` as 3rd argument. But the signature of comparator is a question. And it helps :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, you can use a lambda expression for the comparator:

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), lob,
                           [](T const & x, int n) { return x.f() < n; });
```

If you are a fan of functional composition style, you can also use nested `bind` expressions:

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
auto it = std::lower_bound(
    v.begin(), v.end(), lob,
    std::bind(std::less<int>(), std::bind(&T::f, _1), _2));
```

Comment: I think you have to pass a custom functor with more combinaison as if I remember correctly, some compiler, in Debug, check that the range is sorted according to the given compare functor.

Comment: @Jarod42: Please feel free to test this, look up the standard requirements and post it as an answer.

Comment: Just checked, and the problem arises with VS2008 (not with VS2013). So I think my remark may be considered as obsolete.