# Compare function for std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, stl, comparison, binary-search

I have a class PersonsDB with a member variable `__emails` which is supposed to be a sorted vector of pointers to objects of class Person (sorted by Person emails). My plan was to use lower_bound with custom comparison function to get the iterator of where to insert my next pointer.
Member function `email()` returns just a string.

```
bool PersonsDB::compare_email(Person * person_1, Person * person_2) const {
    return ((*person_1).email() < (*person_2).email());
}

vector<Person *>::iterator PersonsDB::email_exists(const string & email) {

    Person * dummy_person = new Person("", "", email, 0);

    auto i = lower_bound(__emails.begin(), __emails.end(), dummy_person, compare_email);

    if (i != __emails.end() && !((*dummy_person).email() < (*i)->email()))
        return i; // found
    else
        return __emails.end(); // not found

}
```

I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/869661/9305575) that suggests to create a dummy object. My code however wouldn't compile with the following error:

```
   main.cpp:121:87: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool PersonsDB::compare_email(Person*, Person*) const’
         auto i = lower_bound(__emails.begin(), __emails.end(), dummy_person, compare_email);
                                                                                           ^
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Make `compare_email` a static member function.

Comment: And use `operator->` instead of `operator*` and `operator.`, ie:`return person_1->email() < person_2->email();`

Comment: Note that `__email` is a reserved name and your program has undefined behaviour for using it.

Comment: And `email_exist` is a weird name for a function that returns an iterator. `find_by_email`  seems more appropriate.

Comment: Names with double underscores, and names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler. I do not use leading or trailing underscores either. Too hard to remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you're not specifically asking about this, but... there's no need to create a `dummy_person` (let alone on the heap!): `lower_bound` can use a heterogeneous comparison functor:

```
std::vector<Person *>::iterator
PersonsDB::email_exists(const std::string & email) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(
        __emails.begin(), __emails.end(), email,
        [](Person * p, const std::string & s) { return p->email() < s; });

    return (it != __emails.end() && it->email() == email)
           ? it
           : __emails.end();
}
```

The comparison functor is most easily expressed as a lambda, no need for a named function.

Comment: Surely you mean `return p->email() < s;`

Comment: Fix that double underscore. That's UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'd be happy to upvote a more comprehensive answer ;-) Why rentacoder.com when you can delegatetoansouser.net!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.  I just spent half an hour writing up the same question.  It wasn't until I added some tags that the "Similar questions" box pointed me here.